# how to write Oracle Function For Convert Date to persian (jalali)

Tags: database, oracle, function

i want to convert date to Persian date (jalali) in oracle Database
there is any function ?

Comment: Have you tried doing `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR = 'PERSIAN'`?

Comment: If Oracle does not have it's own function you can write one yourself. The following site shows you how to do this. The code is easily translated into PLSQL. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13465/Jalali-Calendar

Comment: ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CALENDAR = 'PERSIAN'
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE ,'DD-MM,YYYY')FROM DUAL
  this code worked for me

Comment: However, some people (at least me!) here don't mind receiving anything because they just feel like helping :-)

Answer (score 26):

You can use this statement:

```
select to_char(hiredate,'yyyy/mm/dd','nls_calendar=persian') from emp
```

`hiredate` is a date field, with this select `hiredate` is displayed in persian

Answer (score -1):

First of all you must set `nls_calendar` to Persian like below:

```
Alter session set nls_calendar=persian;
```

Now you can change format of date like below:

```
Select to_char(sysdate,'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual;
```